# Why won't this form process?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am switching to PDO, already had success with dozens of pages for this development site, and this one was supposed to be a "quickie" form -- should have only taken about ten minutes.  But I'm commencing my second weekend trying to figure out why it won't work.  I know the the following is insecure -- I've stripped it to bare bones to try to figure out why it won't process.  The following does nothing more than reload the form page with fields blank.  I'm not getting any errors, error logs don't show anything, and it never gets to the point of processing the form -- for instance, entering two different passwords isn't shown as an error, echoing variables isn't showing.  It seems it's not even getting to the "if(isset" point -- and I can't figure out why.

```
<?php
try {
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e -> getMessage();
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

    if ($pass1 != $pass2) {
        die ("ERROR: Hey!  The passwords don't match!");
    }

    $stmt = $con -> prepare ("
        INSERT INTO proj_users
            (email, username, password) 
        VALUES 
            (?, ?, ?)
    ");
    $stmt -> bindParam(1,$email);
    $stmt -> bindParam(2,$username);
    $stmt -> bindParam(3,$pass1);
    $stmt -> execute();

    header('Location: /index.php');
} else {
?>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>' method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='label'>Email:  </td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='label'>Username: </td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' maxlength='30' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='label'>Password: </td>
            <td><input type='password' name='pass1' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='label'>Password Again: </td>
            <td><input type='password' name='pass2' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='label alignright' colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Register' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

**UPDATE:**  As I go through and update more of my forms, I run into the same problem -- no "name" attribute, and yet they had been working before I started messing with them.  Didn't take me long to figure out it was because I was re-writing the forms and in the process changing them from "!isset" to "isset" -- so, of course, with no "name," they never were.

Comment: If you are going to be using this code for anything other than practice  *please* do not store passwords in plain text in your database. At the very least they should be hashed using php's `crypt()` function.

Comment: Thank you, Bad Wolf -- I took that out until I could get the form to work.  Now that it is, I'm putting it back in.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type='submit' value='Register' />
```

Should be

```
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Register' />
```

You had forgotten to set a `name` for your Submit button.

Comment: OK, step by step. `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { die('im here!');` does it show `im here` after form submission?

Comment: OK, happy to hear that `:)`

Comment: Good grief!  Thank you for the "step by step" -- I found the typo I made when I was trying to copy/paste the code for my post.  The "name" was the problem and it's working now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you have to set a name attribute for submit button i think

change

```
<input type='submit' value='Register' />
```

to

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the name:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling $_POST['submit'], which is not in your query string. 
Add name to the submit button, as answered.

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register' />
```